# How to resolve domains within a vagrant box?

Tags: macos, nginx, routes, vagrant, debian-jessie

I have a Debian Vagrant box running a Nginx server which hosts two websites/services that should share data via JSON endpoints.

Websites are accessible with `https://app.test` and `https://cdn.app.test` from the browser of the Host MacOS system.

To do this I have setup `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "33.33.33.10"` in the Vagrantfile.

I have added to the `/etc/hosts` file on MacOS:

```
33.33.33.10 app.test
33.33.33.10 cdn.app.test
```

I can access both domains from the Mac, that works.

However I cannot use `curl https://cdn.app.test/` **within** the Vagrant box shell because the Domains won't be resolved.
Neither `curl_init` or `file_get_contents` work.

I guess the problem is that the Vagrant cannot see the MacOS hosts entries.

What is the right way to configure this dev system? What is the easy fix?

Answer (score 0):

The easy fix is to add

```
127.0.0.1       app.test
127.0.0.1       cdn.app.test
```

to `/etc/hosts` in the Debian Vagrant box.

Answer (score 0):

For Vagrant. copy the default config from /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf to /etc/apache2/sites-available/"".conf

```
vagrant ssh // login

sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/"<your-test-domain>".conf
```

Folder name in sites-available should be the exact same as the one that you will be changing in your hosts file later.

Then edit your ServerName and DocumentRoot, enable it -> sudo a2ensite "".conf

restart Apache, edit your hosts file in your host OS.

Inside your hosts file, point to your private IP as specified in Vagrantfile